# Is it possible to read runtime memory (what's stored in variables) of my App?

Tags: ios, swift

Might be a dumb question, but I did not get any concrete answer anywhere.

My iOS app keeps user secrets in runtime memory throughout the lifetime of the app. Is there any way someone can maliciously read the memory data of my app? Like, take a memory snapshot?

If not, is it safe to keep it in runtime memory?

Comment: Ultimately almost anything is possible for a sufficiently determined and skilled person, it's best to evaluate the risks vs cost and determine if it makes sense to add additional layers of security.

Comment: I am storing user data in Keychain, so I think I am covered by the side of storage, but my app requires the user data to be loaded into runtime memory. I saw arguments against some OS vulnerabilities, hence to reduce attack surface it is best to only decrypt data when required, and not store in plaintext in memory.

Comment: Yes, that is reasonable. Seems like you have your answer then?

Comment: Well, I wanted to know how easy it is. Are OS bugs/vulnerabilities and snooping malware that common? Or we are talking about some super-rare case scenario to the level of CIA-MOSSAD level of snooping. 

The reason is, I will require to make the necessary changes ASAP if the vulnerability is that prominent. Otherwise, I will push it for some time later as part of good practices.

Comment: Your app in memory can be easily dumped on jailbroken devices.

Comment: Yes, jailbroken devices is a different case altogether. In that case, even Keychain is not safe. And if the user deliberately jailbreaks their phone, or the phone gets lost, then all bets are off.

Comment: But you should think of "jailbreak" here more broadly as "performing any operation that wasn't meant to be allowed by the OS." You are not supposed to be able to read the memory of other processes (that's one of many points of sandboxing). In the presence of a sandboxing bug, then it may be possible to read other process's memory. There is a huge range of security states between "all pieces work as expected" and "attacker has 100% control of device." So as long as the OS has no bugs, then the answer is no. If the OS has bugs, then maybe.

Comment: This is why very sensitive secrets are stored in memory for as short a time as possible and then overwritten, and Apple has tools like secure enclave to keep some secrets out of main memory. (Note that overwriting memory is harder than it sounds; the optimizer will want to remove the step.) Depending on the sensitivity of your secrets, this may or may not be worth exploring further.